# 99 Camry, suddenly started not accelerating

Tags: toyota, noise, camry, acceleration, random-misfire

My 99 Camry V6 suddenly (like 10 minutes after a normal drive) started having issues accelerating. If i am in park i can rev it and is fine up to 5000 rpm, but in drive, it now hesitates to accelerate normally. When i try, I also hear a fluttering sound from the passenger side towards the engine bay. It holds a speed once i reach it, but accelerating further is an issue.

What could I be dealing with? I checked for codes, nothing new thrown or pending. Also have at least 2 gallons in the car, so it's not just running on fumes.

Update: p0300 misfire code and a blinking check engine light, on my ride home. So spark plugs? Or cables? Last replaced a few years ago.

Comment: see if you can catch it on film yourself or with a friend as passenger / cameraman and upload to YouTube and post a link here. Could be [all](https://repairpal.com/OBD-II-Code-P0300) sorts of reasons unfortunately, you'll need to collect more behavior/evidence.

Comment: Engine bay looks normal while in park. Did you mean a video from inside while driving?